# If one checkbox is checked others are disabled in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a loop for display the address. Depending upon the address, checkbox is also displayed. If one checkbox is checked, other checkboxes should automatically be disabled.

checkbox.html:

```
<div *ngFor ="let cust of customer.Address" >
   <button type="button" class="btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" >  
     <a (click)="showOnEdit(cust)">
       <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit
     </a>                           
  </button>  

  <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="checkIfOthersAreSelected" (change)="checkSelected($event)">                            
</div>
```

checkbox.ts:

```
checkSelected(e)
{
  if(e.target.checked)
  {
    this.checkIfOthersAreSelected = true;
  }
}
```

I tried lot of answers related to this question, but failed to get the result. How to achieve this?

Comment: But what is the problem ?

Comment: I want if one checkbox is selected other checkbox automatically disabled

Comment: Is there a reason to not use radiobuttons?

Comment: For better layout I want to use checkbox

Comment: Radiobuttons are accepting css too

Comment: Can you please create the stackblitz to show the issue?

Comment: please provide this example in 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9admm
to understand more

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the content of `customer.Address` I have in below used `value` and `checked` properties. Assumingly your data doesn't contain a `checked` property. You can add that on the fly, or then add it manually:

```ts
this.customer.Address.forEach((x) => {
  x.checked = false;
})
```

Then in your template you can refer to the `checked` property in `[disabled]` and when user interacts with the checkboxes, call a function with passing the checkbox object. Here we assume that `value` propery is unique, we check the `value` of each object in array, and if value doesn't match, we disable the field. So do the following (sample code):

```html
<div *ngFor="let chk of checkboxes">
 <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="chk.checked" (click)="disableOther(chk)"> {{chk.value}}
</div>
```

and the function:

```ts
disableOther(chk) {
  this.checkboxes.forEach(x => {
    if (x.value !== chk.value) {
      x.checked = !x.checked
    }
  })
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wo895h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can do by getting the element Id like

> HTML

```
<div *ngFor ="let cust of customer.Address" >
   <button type="button" class="btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" >  
   <a (click)="showOnEdit(cust)">
   <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit
   </a>                           
   </button>  
   <input [id]="cust.id"  type="checkbox" [disabled]="checkIfOthersAreSelected" (change)="checkSelected($event , cust.id)">   <!-- You can use even the loop count or any unique name -->                         
</div>
```

In ts, you can do a loop and make other checkboxes disabled

> TS

```
checkSelected(e, id) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        for (let index = 0; index < customer.Address; index++) {
            if (customer.Address[index].id === id) {
                document.getElementById(customer.Address[index].id).disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById(customer.Address[index].id).disabled = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (let index = 0; index < customer.Address; index++) {
            document.getElementById(customer.Address[index].id).disabled = fasle;
        }
    }
}
```